# Durandal js, all functions activate at startup

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

i have a SPA written with Durandal js and knockoutJs packs,
when i run the program all the `function ()` functions triggered at startup,
most of the must be triggered by some actions (like, click events etc...)
and it works fine, but i do not need it to be trigger at startup.
how can i control it?

here is how the main.js looks like:

```
define(jquery, function () { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);
define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'bootstrap'], function (system, app, viewLocator) {

app.title = 'Durandal Starter Kit';

app.configurePlugins({
    router: true,
    dialog: true
});

app.start().then(function () {
    //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
    //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
    viewLocator.useConvention();

    //Show the app by setting the root view model for our application with a transition.
    app.setRoot('shell', 'entrance');
});
```

});

Comment: What functions are triggered? Can you please provide an example or code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be related to how events are bound on the html bindings. If they are used like this
`data-bind="click: clickHandler()"` it will likely call the function as the bindings are processed.
Instead, remove the brackets so it points to a function instead of calling it.
`data-bind="click: clickHandler"`